# Gps heatmap with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gps, heatmap, gpx

I would like to replicate a heatmap like this with R and my gps data
[cool heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8tac.jpg)

I have a DB with activities: lat, long and ID.
For the moment my "solution" is:

```
  heatmap <- ggplot(db) + geom_path(aes(lon,lat, group=id, colour = "white"), db %>% dplyr::filter(lon > 7.15, lon < 7.40, lat > 44.11, lat < 45.28), alpha = 0.3,size = 0.3, lineend = "round") + coord_map() + theme_black() + guides(colour=F)
```

(theme_black it is my function to have black background).

[heatmap with geom_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1NN8.png)

But, sincerly, for the moment I don't like this solution because there aren't big differences between colour (there isn't red and white like desidered) but I don't know what I can do to improve.
Any guesses? Ggplot isn't the best solution for this stuff?

Thanks in advance!!!

Here a sample of data (sorry but it is very large dataset)

```
> dput(db[1:500,])
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), lat = c(45.129635038, 
45.130085063, 45.131009, 45.131882059, 45.131590033, 45.131329021, 
45.13112006, 45.131015035, 45.131039007, 45.131698998, 45.132489998, 
45.133366997, 45.133759019, 45.134701983, 45.135683001, 45.136293036, 
45.136023054, 45.135670009, 45.135460042, 45.135254015, 45.135128035, 
45.135034996, 45.134912033, 45.134307027, 45.133504041, 45.133148984, 
45.133015041, 45.132966007, 45.132905992, 45.132654032, 45.132439036, 
45.131962022, 45.131192983, 45.130391002, 45.129920023, 45.129436052, 
45.129070014, 45.129021986, 45.129591033, 45.129928992, 45.130368036, 
45.13124604, 45.131983061, 45.132388996, 45.132566022, 45.13284405, 
45.132908004, 45.133012023, 45.133217045, 45.133765054, 45.134631994, 
45.134917062, 45.135047988, 45.135109008, 45.135300031, 45.135462054, 
45.135700016, 45.136083991, 45.136218017, 45.135245046, 45.134240056, 
45.133684001, 45.133936044, 45.134249025, 45.134536021, 45.134823017, 
45.135122, 45.13459503, 45.133557015, 45.132596029, 45.131550052, 
45.131247046, 45.131424994, 45.131285016, 45.130373987, 45.129641995, 
45.128759046, 45.128316984, 45.129005055, 45.129666051, 45.122702031, 
45.122991039, 45.122958014, 45.122913003, 45.123416002, 45.124176994, 
45.125018035, 45.12542506, 45.125733011, 45.12628102, 45.126707994, 
45.127108062, 45.127236054, 45.127496983, 45.127754055, 45.128442042, 
45.129054005, 45.129768059, 45.130593006, 45.130973042, 45.131786002, 
45.132748999, 45.13345903, 45.133549052, 45.132284055, 45.131362046, 
45.13043199, 45.129638056, 45.129016035, 45.129181997, 45.129563038, 
45.129855985, 45.130079028, 45.130468032, 45.131136992, 45.131705033, 
45.132078028, 45.132376005, 45.132479018, 45.132704994, 45.132877997, 
45.132926025, 45.132952009, 45.133025015, 45.133105062, 45.133291057, 
45.133701016, 45.134175012, 45.134924019, 45.134991997, 45.135074055, 
45.135140021, 45.135174051, 45.135249991, 45.135427017, 45.135488038, 
45.135602031, 45.13577604, 45.135962034, 45.136227992, 45.136352044, 
45.136202008, 45.135484014, 45.134862999, 45.134246007, 45.13367302, 
45.133871001, 45.134082057, 45.134269057, 45.134495033, 45.134673987, 
45.134855036, 45.13503399, 45.135185032, 45.135087047, 45.134516994, 
45.133909055, 45.133294996, 45.132439036, 45.131882059, 45.131336984, 
45.130725021, 45.130062013, 45.129416019, 45.12933899, 45.128922996, 
45.128330982, 45.128401055, 45.129221056, 45.130106018, 45.130646986, 
45.13123506, 45.131795055, 45.132434007, 45.133362052, 45.134454046, 
45.135240017, 45.135089059, 45.134865011, 45.13461699, 45.13438104, 
45.134141988, 45.133906037, 45.133666985, 45.133435058, 45.133203047, 
45.133004061, 45.13272905, 45.132522017, 45.132340046, 45.13216805, 
45.131994041, 45.131811986, 45.131628003, 45.131385012, 45.131203041, 
45.131021992, 45.130847062, 45.130666012, 45.130484041, 45.130299053, 
45.130098055, 45.129903008, 45.129663034, 45.129481985, 45.129300014, 
45.12912106, 45.12894898, 45.128773043, 45.128603058, 45.128431062, 
45.128258059, 45.128033005, 45.127850028, 45.127668979, 45.127458007, 
45.127250052, 45.127065985, 45.126884014, 45.126703049, 45.126526023, 
45.126340028, 45.126152022, 45.125964016, 45.125770981, 45.125583059, 
45.125393041, 45.125204029, 45.125013006, 45.124807984, 45.124527023, 
45.124449993, 45.124267016, 45.12408999, 45.123908019, 45.123734011, 
45.123548016, 45.123355987, 45.123176028, 45.122982992, 45.122779983, 
45.122572028, 45.12230498, 45.121796031, 45.121328991, 45.120846026, 
45.120289049, 45.119771047, 45.119686055, 45.120316038, 45.120865053, 
45.121838024, 45.122644028, 45.122594994, 45.122980059, 45.12336504, 
45.123782039, 45.12420499, 45.124636993, 45.124972018, 45.125372002, 
45.125795037, 45.12622, 45.126666001, 45.127089035, 45.127513998, 
45.12776403, 45.128168038, 45.128481018, 45.128721998, 45.129045036, 
45.129408056, 45.129672003, 45.129911054, 45.130124039, 45.130358061, 
45.130662995, 45.130887043, 45.131170016, 45.131380989, 45.131610988, 
45.13187703, 45.132096049, 45.132301992, 45.132506008, 45.132714047, 
45.132897024, 45.13332098, 45.133744015, 45.134139054, 45.134440048, 
45.134644986, 45.134853025, 45.135062991, 45.135276059, 45.135480997, 
45.13562701, 45.135738992, 45.135847034, 45.135989024, 45.136178036, 
45.136355062, 45.136536027, 45.136685979, 45.136855042, 45.136982028, 
45.137129047, 45.13734706, 45.137550992, 45.137713014, 45.137870007, 
45.137991041, 45.138122051, 45.138241996, 45.13832506, 45.138433019, 
45.138613985, 45.138707024, 45.138897041, 45.139046994, 45.13924598, 
45.138971054, 45.138756058, 45.138572997, 45.138494039, 45.138537039, 
45.138555982, 45.13856998, 45.138490016, 45.138134037, 45.13817603, 
45.138190028, 45.138119033, 45.138011996, 45.137893057, 45.137830025, 
45.137340019, 45.136485987, 45.136036046, 45.136160015, 45.136310051, 
45.136460003, 45.136604004, 45.136782036, 45.136945986, 45.137076995, 
45.137200041, 45.137354017, 45.137520984, 45.137670015, 45.137808987, 
45.137971009, 45.138123056, 45.138263034, 45.138408041, 45.138550031, 
45.138677016, 45.138722027, 45.138562017, 45.13831802, 45.137910994, 
45.138398989, 45.138588001, 45.138689003, 45.138574003, 45.138490016, 
45.138418016, 45.138348027, 45.138279044, 45.138208049, 45.138142, 
45.138009985, 45.13792801, 45.137807059, 45.137701028, 45.137589045, 
45.137460048, 45.137328033, 45.137216051, 45.137101051, 45.13703299, 
45.136954032, 45.136867028, 45.13679201, 45.136722021, 45.136656056, 
45.136593024, 45.136534015, 45.136470061, 45.136398061, 45.136333017, 
45.136257999, 45.136191028, 45.136120033, 45.136053062, 45.135992041, 
45.136270991, 45.136828052, 45.13735804, 45.137744027, 45.13783606, 
45.137914012, 45.138001016, 45.138095983, 45.138160021, 45.138153986, 
45.138158009, 45.138193045, 45.138021049, 45.137166011, 45.136320025, 
45.135530031, 45.134769038, 45.134702988, 45.135192995, 45.135535982, 
45.135733041, 45.135798, 45.135761036, 45.135694987, 45.135620053, 
45.135560038, 45.135509998, 45.135451995, 45.135401033, 45.135342025, 
45.135242029, 45.134860987, 45.134496039, 45.134132013, 45.13376103, 
45.133521056, 45.133300026, 45.133006994, 45.132452028, 45.131868061, 
45.131346036, 45.131149062, 45.131034984, 45.130921996, 45.130788053, 
45.131065997, 45.131710062, 45.132181041, 45.132570046, 45.133207992, 
45.133852058, 45.135253009, 45.135628015, 45.135519051, 45.135387036, 
45.135186038, 45.134960061, 45.134741042, 45.134521017, 45.134305016, 
45.134094043, 45.133896063, 45.133704033, 45.133504041, 45.133304049, 
45.133121994, 45.132931054, 45.132731062, 45.132539033, 45.132356056, 
45.13217903, 45.131998987, 45.131801006, 45.131603025, 45.131293063, 
45.131077061, 45.130906992, 45.130640029, 45.130429056, 45.130185059, 
45.129916, 45.129638056, 45.129436052, 45.129249052, 45.129059034, 
45.128870022, 45.12869199, 45.128509014, 45.128316984, 45.128100982, 
45.127882047, 45.127689012, 45.127498994, 45.127322052, 45.127143015, 
45.126965989, 45.126790053, 45.126614033, 45.126442036, 45.126274063, 
45.126093014, 45.125907019, 45.12567702, 45.125481051), lon = c(7.177825015, 
7.178235979, 7.178516019, 7.178818019, 7.180071029, 7.181411044, 
7.182807972, 7.184132984, 7.18553603, 7.186470026, 7.186401043, 
7.186276991, 7.187393963, 7.18766101, 7.187816998, 7.188647979, 
7.189946001, 7.191276963, 7.192704988, 7.194035029, 7.195474034, 
7.196896024, 7.198408035, 7.199529031, 7.200370993, 7.201671026, 
7.202974999, 7.204132037, 7.205226965, 7.206691032, 7.208102041, 
7.209466029, 7.210153009, 7.20987297, 7.21114199, 7.212511006, 
7.213782038, 7.213086005, 7.212089983, 7.21093898, 7.209804993, 
7.210080003, 7.209278023, 7.207956029, 7.206746017, 7.205330984, 
7.203929027, 7.202396983, 7.200898969, 7.199761964, 7.199052017, 
7.197729017, 7.196266962, 7.194900041, 7.193565977, 7.192243984, 
7.190915033, 7.189523972, 7.188117992, 7.187784979, 7.187623962, 
7.186670018, 7.185395969, 7.183994012, 7.182630024, 7.181356981, 
7.180001963, 7.179446997, 7.179225044, 7.17899999, 7.178715005, 
7.177729042, 7.176305962, 7.175184045, 7.175042977, 7.175579, 
7.176279978, 7.177192013, 7.177936997, 7.177846975, 7.240954995, 
7.239716988, 7.238274965, 7.237349016, 7.236500013, 7.235478008, 
7.234529009, 7.233205003, 7.231871023, 7.230718009, 7.229324014, 
7.228024987, 7.226928969, 7.22580504, 7.224867021, 7.224035034, 
7.223248979, 7.222385978, 7.221774015, 7.220518993, 7.219154, 
7.218150016, 7.216942016, 7.215428998, 7.215080982, 7.214733971, 
7.214371035, 7.214068029, 7.213604007, 7.212810995, 7.211996022, 
7.211213991, 7.210382003, 7.209782026, 7.210057037, 7.20995, 
7.209150031, 7.208283007, 7.20733099, 7.206362042, 7.205403991, 
7.204609973, 7.203629039, 7.202443, 7.201614029, 7.200698977, 
7.199939996, 7.199496006, 7.199036007, 7.19783597, 7.196806002, 
7.195955993, 7.195093998, 7.194239044, 7.193458018, 7.192641034, 
7.191804017, 7.19099902, 7.190212043, 7.189392041, 7.18862099, 
7.187857985, 7.187763018, 7.187660005, 7.187563026, 7.18674403, 
7.185946995, 7.185042001, 7.184242032, 7.183256991, 7.182461967, 
7.181659987, 7.18086203, 7.180093996, 7.179516986, 7.179345995, 
7.17919797, 7.179040977, 7.178834028, 7.178706036, 7.178580979, 
7.178419962, 7.178262969, 7.177921993, 7.177279017, 7.176531016, 
7.176589019, 7.177392006, 7.178126009, 7.178326001, 7.178472014, 
7.178597994, 7.178737972, 7.178898988, 7.17914902, 7.179385976, 
7.179649001, 7.180366994, 7.181394029, 7.182473031, 7.183556979, 
7.184621984, 7.185677014, 7.186734978, 7.187767041, 7.188773037, 
7.189650036, 7.190855018, 7.191781973, 7.192599963, 7.193384006, 
7.194171989, 7.194980004, 7.195796989, 7.19684699, 7.19766104, 
7.198472995, 7.199277993, 7.200095983, 7.200926043, 7.201757025, 
7.20265699, 7.203524014, 7.204577032, 7.205392005, 7.206207983, 
7.207015998, 7.207799036, 7.208567991, 7.209362009, 7.210172036, 
7.211006036, 7.212032986, 7.212842008, 7.213678019, 7.214617965, 
7.215551039, 7.216375986, 7.217187019, 7.218014983, 7.21882501, 
7.219644006, 7.220502983, 7.221353998, 7.222200989, 7.223062984, 
7.223912993, 7.224756045, 7.225593984, 7.226522028, 7.227319985, 
7.228115009, 7.228928975, 7.229760963, 7.230591023, 7.23134003, 
7.232190039, 7.233049016, 7.233908999, 7.234774012, 7.235642042, 
7.236505964, 7.23738598, 7.238509994, 7.23919798, 7.239701984, 
7.239998033, 7.240014042, 7.240470018, 7.240710998, 7.24098802, 
7.241482971, 7.241980018, 7.236541001, 7.234863028, 7.233077012, 
7.231303988, 7.229408001, 7.227598013, 7.225949041, 7.224104017, 
7.222255975, 7.220355043, 7.218403987, 7.216424014, 7.214443035, 
7.21335498, 7.211516996, 7.210116045, 7.209041988, 7.207609018, 
7.206005979, 7.204825975, 7.203763987, 7.202810043, 7.20175803, 
7.200392032, 7.199333984, 7.198078962, 7.197141027, 7.196108041, 
7.19506902, 7.194110969, 7.193170016, 7.192237027, 7.191262044, 
7.190321007, 7.188476989, 7.186560969, 7.18479901, 7.183440974, 
7.182486023, 7.181530989, 7.180590037, 7.179652018, 7.178611992, 
7.177518991, 7.176512995, 7.175524015, 7.17428299, 7.172614991, 
7.17101497, 7.169426012, 7.168046016, 7.166526964, 7.165433963, 
7.164168045, 7.162294019, 7.160434996, 7.159037985, 7.157677015, 
7.156510003, 7.155374003, 7.154417041, 7.153558986, 7.152548045, 
7.151016, 7.149832978, 7.148454994, 7.14724297, 7.145434994, 
7.14365803, 7.141911996, 7.14024098, 7.139148986, 7.137836044, 
7.136638019, 7.135302027, 7.134236017, 7.132942019, 7.130933044, 
7.129730995, 7.128744026, 7.127353971, 7.125574996, 7.124366996, 
7.122896978, 7.121798027, 7.120348041, 7.118866037, 7.117006009, 
7.114993011, 7.112969033, 7.110609024, 7.108462, 7.10662301, 
7.104880999, 7.102604977, 7.10047304, 7.098388042, 7.096420977, 
7.094558015, 7.092581981, 7.090666968, 7.088789003, 7.086752032, 
7.085011027, 7.08365098, 7.082186997, 7.080838013, 7.08017601, 
7.081466991, 7.082715978, 7.084399987, 7.086051976, 7.087146988, 
7.088107973, 7.089052027, 7.090004965, 7.090939045, 7.091842027, 
7.093496028, 7.094554998, 7.096346965, 7.097899964, 7.099425973, 
7.101134037, 7.102866996, 7.104503981, 7.106013981, 7.107015032, 
7.108085988, 7.109268004, 7.110304007, 7.111242026, 7.112125981, 
7.112966016, 7.113799009, 7.114587998, 7.115390984, 7.116221044, 
7.117093013, 7.117956014, 7.118815997, 7.119701964, 7.120579969, 
7.121648997, 7.12239398, 7.123135024, 7.124066002, 7.125184986, 
7.126317968, 7.127448016, 7.128650987, 7.129692019, 7.130693992, 
7.131727984, 7.133294981, 7.134498035, 7.134834988, 7.135549964, 
7.136335013, 7.136930044, 7.137892035, 7.139461966, 7.14130699, 
7.142842974, 7.143689043, 7.14469001, 7.146057015, 7.147123025, 
7.148335971, 7.14946099, 7.150665972, 7.151748998, 7.15290503, 
7.153922006, 7.155127994, 7.156057966, 7.156963966, 7.157977003, 
7.158876968, 7.159796044, 7.160927014, 7.162616973, 7.164022032, 
7.16541502, 7.166560994, 7.167449979, 7.168308034, 7.169376978, 
7.17003303, 7.170956045, 7.171747045, 7.17239899, 7.173422001, 
7.173888035, 7.174727985, 7.176419034, 7.177881006, 7.178866969, 
7.17985201, 7.180855995, 7.181842964, 7.182824988, 7.183801982, 
7.184746036, 7.185595039, 7.186423003, 7.187330009, 7.188232991, 
7.189049976, 7.189923035, 7.190823, 7.191693041, 7.192525029, 
7.193338995, 7.194151034, 7.195040019, 7.195914, 7.197277987, 
7.198237966, 7.198999965, 7.200217018, 7.20117004, 7.20226304, 
7.203474979, 7.204716004, 7.205629045, 7.206463044, 7.207314981, 
7.208162978, 7.20899002, 7.209822008, 7.210690038, 7.211654041, 
7.212608991, 7.213448019, 7.214296016, 7.215085005, 7.215888997, 
7.216691983, 7.217486001, 7.218272978, 7.219039, 7.219812985, 
7.220614044, 7.221435973, 7.222482035, 7.223379988)), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data so we can reproduce it? You can use `dput(db)` and post the output here.

Comment: Added sample data. I removed time variable because I think it isn't useful. Hope it helps, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a single color whereas there are multiple groups in your data. This is why your `colour = "white"` is not taken. As a kind of 'hack', I've colored by `id` and then changed the range of colors from white to white. For clarity reasons, I've taken the `dplyr` part out of the `part`. Also, I don't have your `theme_black` function, so I've just manually added the black background:

```
db_plot <- db %>% filter(lon > 7.15, lon < 7.40, lat > 44.11, lat < 45.28)
ggplot(db_plot, aes(lon,lat, group = id, col = id)) + 
  geom_path(alpha = 0.3, size = 0.5, lineend = "round") +
  coord_map() +
  guides(colour=F) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
  scale_color_continuous(low = "white", high = "white")
```

[image]

The image you posted seems to have different color ranges according to how many times a path has been taken. In order to achieve that, I think you need to have your data grouped by frequency of points. Then you can use that group to color and have a continuous range from red to white.